# How to mount both App and Phone Storage over USB for HTC Evo?

Tags: usb, htc-evo

I can mount my HTC Evo as a USB drive on my Windows 7 machine.

When I mount the drive, I see a DCIM/100Media file, but no photos from my phone are in it.  (I'm wanting to transfer photos from my phone to my computer)

When I look at Settings -> Storage, it says,

- App Storage, 4.41/6.07 GB
- Phone Storage, 1.8 GB / 9.93 GB

  - Photos and Videos 1.65 GB

But when I look at the properties of my G: drive (how it's mounted on the machine) it appears that I have mounted the App Storage, because my Windows box says, the drive I have mounted has used 5.65 GB of 7.40 GB total.

So, I believe I have the wrong drive mounted?  Is it possible to mount both the "Phone Storage" and "App Storage" as USB?  If so, I haven't figured  it out.  gone through all USB and Storage setting screens I could find.....

Comment: Is drive G: the only one that shows up, or do you get a drive H: as well? Does Windows give you any choices when the phone is plugged in?

Comment: @TreborRude G: is the only one that shows up.  Windows gives me no choices.

Comment: Do you keep your photos on an sd card or on the internal storage?

Comment: @John "Phone" not "SD" based on the settings menu.  Ah, so apparently the SD card is getting mounted, and not internal storage...  Know how to mount internal storage?

Comment: 1. Can you check in the start > right click My Computer >properties then select the Device Manager check under Universal Serial Bus controllers if there is a conflict(driver issue)? 2. Can you check in the start > right click My Computer > manage > storage > Disk Management if there is an drive letter added to your phone storage? If there is no drive letter added it will not be visible.

Comment: Any of you that have commented, feel free to answer this and I'll accept.  The phone now mounts with multiple drives.  I think the problem was I had never seen that before, and just missed it?  My home machine has a lot of drives.  I saw one, and missed the second.  One drive mounts for the phone memory, one mounts for the SSDCard.

Comment: @John as none of the commenters followed your request, you might wish to sum up your solution yourself, and later accept it. That way it's at least easy to see the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone now mounts with multiple drives. I think the problem was I had never seen that before on my previous phones and just missed it!! :(  My home machine has a lot of drives. I saw one, and missed the second. One drive mounts for the phone memory, one mounts for the SSDCard.